# Any ideas on why a "flutter install" to an android device doesn't show anything but "flutter run" works fine

Tags: android, flutter

I have a large / fairly complex Flutter application we've been writing for a few months.  Soo -- we've been running against the simulator etc and on real-devices with flutter run (via usb cable) on various Android devices without issue ..

However, to publish we obviously have to create a APK package etc.  This is where it gets odd --

A "flutter install" of the same build that "flutter run" works fine does not show any artifacts on the device, either emulator or physical. There is no Icon that shows up (our custom one) - - no app shows in the "App List" .. However, in the Settings -> Apps   one DOES see our application listed .. but it doesn't do anything when tapped ...

We're sort of wits end here -- oh, and everything works just fine w/ iOS .. we can publish with TestFlight no problems.. so the issue is pure Android ..

We are pretty sure it must be something to do with the the Manifest.xml file .. but we've been looking at it and looking at it and nothing is popping out that, to us, explains this behavior.  Why does "flutter run" work and "flutter install" does not?

And it's not just my environment -- any of the other 3 programmers have the exact same issue / problem .. and "flutter doctor -v" is all green and again, "flutter run" works as expected (i.e. the app is installed and launched and runs) ..

Has anyone seen this?  Any ideas on how to debug what Android isn't liking in the package?  We're sort of newbie Android developers with just know enough knowledge to be dangerous :)

TIA!

Comment: Have you tried 'flutter build apk' then 'flutter install'?

Comment: @DuncanHoggan - Oh yes .. did that too with the same exact results as doing a flutter clean/flutter run/flutter install.  A APK is built (45Mb) or so and it appears to "install" it -- but nothing shows ..

Comment: I'd say next thing to check is the build.gradle for your app, not the project level file the app specific one. Should be... {project root}/android/app/build.gradle check the AppID in defaultConfig

Answer (score 5):

OK -- so here is the actual answer -- the problem WAS the Manifest .. I had the intent-filter section rather wrong when I added deep-links and created an "impossible" intent that couldn't be ever satisfied.

Old Manifest.xml intent:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    <!-- Deep Links -->
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="missionmode4" />
</intent-filter>
```

The intent-filter is AND logic .. creating an impossible Intent .. the new and working version is:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
 </intent-filter>
 <!-- Deep Links -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="missionmode4" />
</intent-filter>
```

That creates two separate intent filters .. one for the launcher and then one for the deep links as desired.

Voila!

Comment: Thanks.  Perfect Solution.